# Is that class method async ? (no instance)

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I have a very simple question, I've been looking around but I can't find the solution.

Take that code :

```js
class Foo {
  bar = () => {
      return 'string'
  }

  baz = async() => {
      return 'promise'
  }
}
```

I want to know if a specific method of a class is async or not.

```js
isAsync(Foo, 'bar') // false
isAsync(Foo, 'baz') // true
```

the thing is ... I DO NOT want to instantiate it.
All the solutions I found uses "getOwnPropertyNames" on a class instance to get the functions.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: It's not possible without instantiation in your example because `bar` and `baz` don't exist until an instance is created.

Comment: Checking for this is not a good idea. Any async function could easily be refactored into a normal function that returns a promise, and the other way around and that should not affect runtime behavior. For example, if your `bar` function did `bar = () => this.baz();` would you really expect that to behave differently from `baz` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the thing is ... I DO NOT want to instantiate it. All the solutions I found uses "getOwnPropertyNames" on a class instance to get the functions.
>
> Is it possible ?

In your specific example, `bar` and `baz` are [*instance class fields*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). It's the same as writing

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = () => {
       return 'string'
    };

    this.baz = async() => {
        return 'promise'
    };
  }
}
```

The properties (and functions) don't exist until you actually created an instance of the class.

So the answer for this specific case is **no**.

If you declare the functions as "normal" class methods then you can simply look at the constructor function's `prototype` property.

Comment: thanks ! I somehow forgot I wasn't using "normal" class methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
// the most simple way is
const isAsync = (someClass, name) => {
  if (name in someClass.prototype) 
    return someClass.prototype[name][Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction'

  const newInstance = new someClass()
  if (name in newInstance)
    return newInstance[name][Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is that possible to achieve this without creating a new instance ?

Comment: @KevinGilbert, this way no, but if you will do not anonimous, but `async baz () {}` instead of  `baz = async()` then yes you can do it through `someClass.prototype[name][Symbol.toStringTag]`

Comment: @KevinGilbert, i updated my answer that it could work in both ways

Comment: Of course `const newInstance = new someClass()` might not work or have undesired side effects...

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, it can not be universal, but in this particular case it is the only option, otherwise only parsing class code will solve the problem

Comment: You should add that caveat to your answer because people will just copy and paste this.

Comment: @FelixKling, this will be good for them, they should learn that instantiating of a class should not cause side effects, and will start follow FP